# Finding Highest, Middle and lowest value in a MySql using IF ELSE & Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create php code that identifies and labels it if the result is top1, top2 or top3 using `PHP Codes` (If else and Loop). The scenario is I gathered data from the user. I allowed them to rate these three nominees `( clang, bes, tin, mark and yong);`. But at the end of the calculation out of 5 nominees only 3 nominees will be collected and

here's my sql statement:

```
$res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from Award_Final_Calculation WHERE award_description = 'Sunshine Award' ORDER BY score DESC limit 3");`
```

here's my php code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $row['name']." "."got"." "$row['score']." "."Score";
}
```

I want to label them if top1 top2 or top 3

This is my current output:

`clang got 5 Score`

`mark got 2 Score`

`tin got 1 Score`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using SQL and the GROUP BY clause.

```
$res=mysqli_query($link,"select name, COUNT(*) AS score from Award_Final_Calculation WHERE award_description = 'Sunshine Award' GROUP BY name ORDER BY score DESC limit 3");`
```

The results from this query should work with the while loop you've got in your PHP.